# PECL install solr error `php_bin d:\xampp\php\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php.exe ...`

Tags: php, solr

Was trying to install solr extension from pecl using `pecl install solr` but getting this error `php_bin d:\xampp\php\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php.exe, but config variable php_suffix does not match`

Answer (score 3):

In order to fix the error run the following commands in sequence but replace the paths with the ones of your php installation folder . This fixed for me . By first command you tell the config where the php binary folder is . By the second command you append the php executable file.

```
pecl config-set php_bin C:\xampp\php
pecl config-set php_suffix \php.exe
```

Comment: Mind the difference between php binary folder , php executable file(suffix) and slashes .

Answer (score 2):

I think that is a warning. Try run these commands in terminal:

```
pecl config-set php_suffix \php-cgi.exe
pecl config-set php_bin C:\pathto\php\php-cgi.exe
```

Comment: I actually had to use php_suffix set to just .exe due to my path having dots in it.